# where does a CFC get it's Application Scope

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, application.cfc

I have a group of CFC's that I access from two seperate Applicaiton scopes.

One /Application.cfc is in the Root.

The other Application is in /Admin/Application.cfc
The cfcs are in in /_cfc/

If I call a cfc (using createObject())from a page in (for example) /Admin/members/edit.cfm, does this cfc get it's Application scope from:

Application 1: /Application.cfc

or

Application 2: /Admin/Application.cfc

The calling page is under Application 2, but the CFC itself is under Application 1.

I hope I am making sense.

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scopes are dependant on the context in which a cfc is instantiated and not its physical location.

So given your example a cfc that lives under Application1 instantiated from a template in Application2 will see the application scope from Application2

Answer (score 0):

Application is dependant on the name. Thus if I had two applications with different names, thats 2 sets of application scope variables.

The name of the application is normally defined like this

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset this.name = 'myApplication' />
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks Dale.  They both have different application names.  That part is fine. I'm just wanting to confirm if a CFC get's it's application scope from the Application it physically sits under, or from the page that invoked it.